# Importing an object from Blender into a scene, rotation on X axis?

Tags: coordinates, assimp, mesh, importing

This is my situation:

[image]

I save the scene with blender no export with any processing steps.

Blender has x right y up -z into the scene for the view coordinates (OpenGL)
I have x right y up -z into the scene for the view coordinates (OpenGl)
Bleneder has x/y plane and z up as world coordinates
I have x/y plane and z up as world coordinates

I load the mesh with assimp directly from the blend file with absolutely no post processing.
The object is rotated abount π/2 on the x-axis. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Blender does not have  "x right y up -z into the scene", as you can see in your example image, the blue arrow in Blender represents the Z axis. It's pointing up.

You need to either rotate the object in Blender before exporting, or rotate the object as part of your import process.

Blender uses a Z up, Y into the scene coordinates system. You need to change it to match the Y up, Z into the scene coordinates system of OpenGL.

Comment: when I say "x right y up -z into the scene" I am talking about the camera coordinate system. Those coordinates I have after my scene is transformed by the ModelView matrix. The axis in the image describe the world coordine system as I have written above. Tho solution with the rotation I've done so far, but that was not my question, the question was why do i need to process anything if everything else matches.

Comment: I guess I'm still not clear on the question then. The object you're exporting is using the world coordinates, not the camera coordinates.