# Unity importing Blender models with different orientations

Tags: unity, blender

[image]

All the models apart from 'Jungle Tree' are facing right which is not a problem, because they still seem to work with my game. But how can I change the 'Jungle Tree' to face right like the other models instead of left? I haven't made the Jungle Tree drastically different to the other models so I don't see why it is doing this

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know you can't do that in Unity, when importing an object. You'd have to re-export your object with blender. You can either rotate the object itself, or while exporting, play with the settings on the left. There you can change which axis is "Up" and which one is "Forward".

Alternatively you can make the Jungle Tree child of an `Empty` and rotate that by the required amount, but assuming you want to use other objects in a similar way, it can get messy.

Answer (score 2):

First before exporting if you want to keep the rotation as 0 0 0 . Then you have to apply it.

[image: Apply rotation Blender]

When exporting to Unity from Blender as fbx. Blender tends to rotate by 90 degrees.

[image: Fbx Blender export settings]

If you use .blend files in Unity, they will be rotated. For other types of files there are other settings. But fbx is a choice of mine because it can save animations, materials, textures data...

You can also try to change up and forward axis.

Related: [Importing an object from Blender into a scene, rotation on X axis?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/62488/importing-an-object-from-blender-into-a-scene-rotation-on-x-axis) .

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps in blender:

1. Select your model that you want to export to unity
2. Click `R` then `X` and enter in `-90`. This will rotate the model on the x axis by -90 degrees.
3. Click `Ctrl + A` and select `Rotation & Scale`. This will apply the rotation to the model and set its value to 0.
4. Click `R` then `X` and enter in `90`. This will rotate the model back to its original orientation.
5. Export the model as `fbx` into unity.

In Unity you will see that the model is now correctly oriented.